# All caps constants in JavaScript. And requireds. And imports

Tags: javascript, import, constants, require

I was used to declare constant values using all caps. Then I started using `const` for any value that never changes. Suddenly most things are constants. That is ok.

But the code starts to look very different.

It was talked about already: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/278652/how-much-should-i-be-using-let-vs-const-in-es6

I am ok with "go ahead and `const` all the things!". I guess. There will be a lot of all caps around my code.

But there is more.

By this logic required stuff should be constants? I never reassigned a required. So, yes?

```
const GULP = require('gulp');
const ESLINT = require('gulp-eslint');
```

And imports are not reassignable so it should be:

```
import SOMETHING from 'modules/something';
```

Right?

I am looking for references. Best practices about constants. Someone who thought this out for longer and better than I did so far.

Or should I just choose any option and be consistent from then on?

I could not find a discussion considering at least all these points to help me organize my ideas about it. Yet.

Answer (score 36):

Generally speaking it is common practice to capitalize your constants. This is a convention which tells other programmers that the value is fixed. The javascript keyword `const`, though confusing is not a constant in that sense. I think that is where you got confused. A constant is a concept/construct. Not a primitive type within the language. You can use `const` to denote constants (and you should) but not every `const` is a constant :-) Basically a constant is a variable whose value can't or won't change during program execution. Javascripts' `const` variable can change it just can't be reassigned. Reassigning a value and mutating a value are two different things.

```
const foo = [1];
// allowed
foo.pop()
push(2);

// not allowed
foo = [];
```

Basically it was more or less added to give programmers a somewhat shallow immutable type. Everybody uses const because it's the safest type of variable to use if you want catch assignment errors and it is block scoped like let. And there's also a slight performance benefit for using `const` over `let`.

Something like `const gulp = require('gulp');` although using `const` here is perfect, it is not a constant. It's a reference to a function with ever changing values.

So do keep to the convention but only when it concerns a CONSTANT. For example, if you were to build some sort of html5 video player and offer different playback speeds.

```
defaultPlaybackSpeed = 1; // Nothing wrong with this
doubleSpeedMultiplier = 2; // Nothing wrong with this
DEFAULT_PLAYBACK_SPEED = 1; // This though tells others this value is fixed
DOUBLE_SPEED_MULTIPLIER = 2; // Same here
```

Comment: "Something like const gulp = require('gulp'); although using const here is perfect, it is not a constant. It's a reference to a function with ever changing values." +1. Before choosing constant case, consider whether the field _really_ feels like a deeply immutable constant.

Answer (score 11):

Just because other languages use capital letters for constants, I don't think that means the same automatically applies to JavaScript.

The only argument *for* capital letters I can think of is to visually differentiate what can be reassigned, and what cannot. That said, with tools like eslint are capable of warning you when you do something like:

- trying to reassign a variable declared with `const` (i.e. use `let` instead).
- declaring a variable with `let` and not ever reassigning it (i.e., use `const` instead).

The one exception to this rule is defining mathematical constants, or other hard-coded values which don't make sense to be externally configurable - for example `DECAY_RATE`, or something of that nature.

Comment: I think all caps for constants is pretty much established for JavaScript too: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: I am also not sure immutability has anything to do with it. Const just makes a variable non reassignable. Very different thing...

But thank you!

Comment: You're quite right! I've been using immutable.js heavily recently and the muscle memory is just too strong... answer updated to reflect this.

Answer (score 8):

Interesting.
I was reading the book [You Don't Know JS: Up & Going](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/up%20%26%20going/ch1.md) and saw that:

> By convention, JavaScript variables as constants are usually
>   capitalized, with underscores `_` between multiple words.

Then I researched a little more and found that some other developers sites do recommend that you use uppercase, as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) says:

```
// NOTE: Constants can be declared with uppercase or lowercase, but a common
// convention is to use all-uppercase letters.

// define MY_FAV as a constant and give it the value 7
const MY_FAV = 7;
```

Besides that, I have also noticed that they do say that is a convention to use `_` between words.

I've read that this is a common practice among some languages, but I haven't noticed Javascript projects with the code written in this way. And besides that, I always see someone saying that JS is camelCase, so that's a little confusing to me. Anyway, I'm new to it.

I believe the important is that you code something good for you and for others who may work with your code. As long as you be consistent with your projects, and follow the same way your team writes the code I'm sure it's ok.

If you are used to uppercase and `_` , then I would go for:

```
const GULP = require('gulp');
const ESLINT = require('gulp-eslint');
```